# Edit a directory inside Vim

Tags: insert-mode, working-directory

Is it possible to edit a directory inside Vim? (Some commands are working for directories).

I want to know what kind of operations can be done in a directory inside Vim. Vim can open the directories for editing, I believe it will have commands also to work with. But usual commands behave differently for directories.

For example, pressing <kbd>I</kbd> and typing a filename and saving the directory. When I give `ls`, it should show that file.

Comment: I would love the ability to rename files when viewing a directory listing as a text file. I don't see anything out there :(

Comment: Actually you can do `:e some/directory`. I'm not sure what it does though...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `netrw` here, as it's the default action when you do `vim .` or `vim some/directory/`.

You can create a file/directory from `netrw` with the following commands:

```
d : create a directory, you will be prompted to input the directory name
% : create a file, same workflow
```

Have a look at `:h netrw` for more informations.

Comment: See `:h netrw-quickmap` for bindings.

Answer (score 3):

Totally a different angle, but it works without having to install any plugins ...

When I want to create or rename a directory *from a running Vim session*, I'll simply type <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> followed by the appropriate shell command, doing something like the following:

For Linux

- `:! mkdir newdir` to create a directory
- `:! mv newdir renamed_dir` to rename a directory

For Windows

- `:! mkdir newdir` to create a directory
- `:! move newdir renamed_dir` to rename a directory

As far as I know, you can literally execute whatever shell command you like this way without having to exit from Vim or having to open a separate terminal window.

Comment: Thanks. but I am not asking about shell commands. I want to explore the options related to editing directory, like we edit a file.

Comment: It's worth knowing the https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch plugin also.